# VueJS iframe not loading any other html file except the index.html in public folder

Tags: javascript, html, vue.js, iframe

In my vue component's template I am using:

`<iframe width="1000vw" height="600vh" src="../../public/myHtmlFile.html"></iframe>`

But the file given in src is not loading, instead, it is loading whatever there is in the public/index.html file. How do I load myHtmlFile.html with iframe instead?

Note: same thing happened when myHtmlFile.html was in other src/components folder.

Answer (score 1):

Let's say your server is running on http://localhost:3000.

The `src` of the iframe is `http://localhost:3000/../../public/myHtmlFile.html`. This url isn't valid, it's not a relative path like for a file system.

Actually, by default, the `public/` folder is served as the root of the server. So actually `public/myFile.txt === http://localhost:3000/myFile.txt`.

Try with

```html
<iframe width="1000vw" height="600vh" src="/myHtmlFile.html"></iframe>
```

Comment: Does not work, not a problem of path. Whatever html I load, gets overridden by the public/index.html of the project. Any idea why?

Comment: Could you try to rename this file to something else than `index`?